# Would this phrase be set off by commas?

Tags: commas

Would "*about three days ago*" be set off by commas in the sentence,

> "*My parents bought these cups about three days ago for drinking tea*"?

What if "*about*" was removed? Example:

> "*My parents bought these cups three days ago for drinking tea*."

Comment: Commas would not be typically used in either of these sentences, but of course there is no "rule" prohibiting them. Use them just as you please.

Comment: Your examples don't even have a comma!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Commas are a literary tool used to insert pauses into a written sentence, to mimic the pauses in the conversation if the sentence was spoken.  In this English is the same as any other language that uses commas.  There are numerous "rules" around the use of commas, but you'll find these are actually more *guidelines* for good, readable style, and usually not *required*.

So it's a question of style, not grammar.  Are you the sort of writer who likes a lot of commas?  Or do you think they unnecessarily break up the sentence?

> My parents bought these cups about three days ago for drinking tea.
>
> My parents bought these cups, about three days ago, for drinking tea.

Both of these are fine. Just write it as if you were speaking it and put the pauses/commas where it feels natural.

Now, all that being said, there is this thing called the [*Royal Order of Adverbs*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Order-of-Adverbs.htm) which is not a *rule* but just a guide as to the recommended order.  If you choose to write your adverbs in a different order, you may choose to separate them by commas so that the reader can parse the sentence more easily.

> My parents bought these cups for drinking tea, about three days ago.

With the adverbs in this order, we aren't sure whether your parents *bought* the cups three days ago, or your parents *drank tea* three days ago.  The comma helps us recognize that the three days probably applies to *bought*.