# "Commas are a tool" or "Comma is a tool"?

Tags: grammar

An ELL post (https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/107972/109190) says

> *Commas are* a literary tool used to insert pauses into a written sentence, to mimic the pauses in the conversation if the sentence was spoken.

where I guess "Commas are" should be "Comma is", since there is only one type of comma. Is my understanding right?

Answer (score 1):

No, that sentence is referring to multiple instances of that type of punctuation mark. "Comma" is singular.

A comma: ,

Multiple commas: ,,,,,,,,,,,,,

---

Even when there is a different word for describing multiple groups/types, the term that refers to the members of a single group is still a plural.

For example, "People are angry." Or "The fish are swimming"

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "multiple groups/types" and its relevance here? In British English, *Parliament* refers to the collective members of a single (legislative) group, and it's considered plural: "Parliament are sitting." In American English, it's singular: "Congress is in session."

Comment: WXJ mentioned that "multiple types/single type" was their reasoning for choosing the singular. So that's why I added that.